# Function does not return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, return, return-value

I've only started to learn how to refactor code and I'm failing at abstracting a simple function. I pass the parameters into `checkAnwser` and it works, but `count` is "lost"

I can't get/append "count" here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/3sb78uhh/7/)

```
<input data-correctanswer="javascript" id="answer1" name="" type="text">This works fine (no special chars)
<br/>
<button id="btn1">check 1</button>
<br/>
<input data-correctanswer="jávascripté" id="answer2" name="" type="text"> 
<br/>
<button id="btn2">check 2</button>
<div style="border: 1px solid;" id="result"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

         var count;
         $('#btn1').click(function () {
             checkAnswer($('#answer1').data('correctanswer'), $('#answer1').val());
             $('#result').append('result: ').append(count); <-- does not read count
     }); // end of click
     $('#btn2').click(function () {
         checkAnswer($('#answer2').data('correctanswer'), $('#answer2').val());
         $('#result').append('result: ').append(count); // <-- does not read count
     }); // end of click


         function checkAnswer(coorAns, UserAnswer) {
             var count = 0;
             //  var coorAns = $('input[type=text]').data('correctanswer');
             //  var UserAnswer = $('input[type=text]').val();
             var mistakesAllowed = 1;

             if (UserAnswer === coorAns) {
                 count = count + 2;
             }
             for (i = 0; i < coorAns.length; i++) {
                 if (coorAns.charAt(i) !== UserAnswer.charAt(i)) {
                     mistakesAllowed--; // reduce one mistake allowed
                     if (mistakesAllowed < 1) { // and if you have more mistakes than allowed
                         count = count + 1;
                     }
                     if (mistakesAllowed < 0) {
                         count = count - 2
                         break;
                     }
                 }
             }
             console.log('final count: ' + count);
             return count;
         }

     });
```

Comment: You're returning `count` but you're not storing it anywhere, you're misunderstanding variable scope and how returning values from a function works.

Comment: You'll need `var count = checkAnswer(args);`

Comment: I guess that's what I get for learning .slideDown() and .addClass() first, and actual programming after. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Adeneo said:

```
 var count; //here it's defined.
 $('#btn1').click(function () {
     count = checkAnswer($('#answer1').data('correctanswer'), $('#answer1').val());
     $('#result').append('result: ').append(count); 
 }); // end of click
 $('#btn2').click(function () {
     count = checkAnswer($('#answer2').data('correctanswer'), $('#answer2').val());
     $('#result').append('result: ').append(count); 
 }); // end of click
```

Your function `checkAnswer` returns a value called `count`. That value can be assigned to the variable `count`.

Probably the chain of thought you had was that assigning `count` in the function `checkAnswer` would also assign it to the variable `count` outside the function. However those two variables are in two different [`scopes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) and are not connected to eachother unless you assign the result of the function to the variable `count` outside the function.

*To be more precise*:

`checkAnswer` is in the same scope as the first `count` variable. That means you could do this:

```
var count = 0;
console.log(count); //will log 0.
function checkAnswer()
{
   count = 1;
}
checkAnswer();
console.log(count); //will log 1.
```

However when you use the operator `var` inside a function it will create a variable that is bound to the scope of the function (it becomes a private variable) only accessible within that function. Unless you return it to a variable outside the scope of that function.

```
var count = 0;
console.log(count); //will log 0.
function checkAnswer()
{
   var count = 1;
}
checkAnswer();
console.log(count); //will log 0.
```

More on scopes on Stack Overflow:

[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

**Bonus**:

A little efficiency suggestion for your code

```
 var count;
 $('#btn1', '#btn2').click(function () {
     var buttonId = $(this).attr("id").substr(4); //will result in 1 or 2
     count = checkAnswer($('#answer' + buttonId ).data('correctanswer'), $('#answer' + buttonId ).val());
     $('#result').append('result: ').append(count); 
 }); // end of click
```

This will reduce it to one generic function. So when you need to update your code you only need to update one function, not multiple instances of the same code.

Comment: I wasn't hoping for such a detailed answer AND efficiency suggestions :). Thank you!

Comment: It's a site for solutions and learning. I find it important to explain an answer so you and I both learn more about programming.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
 checkAnswer($('#answer2').data('correctanswer'), $('#answer2').val());
```

use

```
var count=checkAnswer($('#answer2').data('correctanswer'), $('#answer2').val()); //Stored returned value to count variable.
```

Now you can access returned value.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/3sb78uhh/8/) is your updated fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for updating the fiddle, I sometimes struggle to implement suggestions myself.